Problem calling Python functions from C using the Python C API
I am trying to call Python functions from a C program using the Python C API. However, I am facing some problems and am not getting the expected results. Below is the code I'm using:
// main.c
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h> // Adding required inclusion for printf
int main() {
    // Initialize the Python interpreter
    Py_Initialize();

    // Import the Python module that contains our functions
    PyObject *pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("funcoes_python");

    // Checks if the import was successful
    if (pModule != NULL) {
        // Gets the references to the functions we want to call
        PyObject *pFuncSoma = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "soma");
        PyObject *pFuncSubtracao = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "subtracao");

        // Call the functions and print the results
        if (pFuncSoma && PyCallable_Check(pFuncSoma)) {
            PyObject *pArgs = PyTuple_Pack(2, PyLong_FromLong(10), PyLong_FromLong(5));
            PyObject *pResult = PyObject_CallObject(pFuncSoma, pArgs);
            long result = PyLong_AsLong(pResult);
            printf("Soma: %ld\n", result);
            Py_XDECREF(pArgs);
            Py_XDECREF(pResult);
        }

        if (pFuncSubtracao && PyCallable_Check(pFuncSubtracao)) {
            PyObject *pArgs = PyTuple_Pack(2, PyLong_FromLong(10), PyLong_FromLong(5));
            PyObject *pResult = PyObject_CallObject(pFuncSubtracao, pArgs);
            long result = PyLong_AsLong(pResult);
            printf("Subtracao: %ld\n", result);
            Py_XDECREF(pArgs);
            Py_XDECREF(pResult);
        }

        // Release references
        Py_XDECREF(pFuncSoma);
        Py_XDECREF(pFuncSubtracao);
    } else {
        PyErr_Print();
        
    }

    // End the Python interpreter
    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}


Code in python:
# funcoes_python.py

def soma(a, b):
    return a + b

def subtracao(a, b):
    return a - b

I expected this code to call the Python "addition" and "subtraction" functions and print the results. However, I am not getting the expected results. Instead, I'm getting.
g++ main.c -o output -L C:/Python312/libs -lpython3 -I C:/Python312/include
.\output.exe

it creates the output.exe file, but does not show any results in the terminal.
This should print:
Sum: 15
Subtraction: 5

Could anyone help me identify what is wrong in this code and how can I fix it to get the expected results?
Config:

Python 3.12
Windows 10 SO

I've already tried Python 64/32 bits.

For the second line of expected output, there isn't any printf.  For the first line failing to output, my guess is that there is either a problem during the import module, or when it attempts to find the function in the file.  Perhaps there is something strange about the format of the python file - can you import it into a normal script and check it works?

By the way, I just tried it on Linux, and apart from having to set export PYTHONPATH=. it worked for me.

Reply to Comment 1: I checked. Everything is ok with the files (functions).
Reply to Comment 2: Great news, later you will be implementing in Ubuntu.
Can you explain or provide a link to configure export PYTHONPATH= in Windows? Today I had a lot of problems with this

To import the module, I needed to set PYTHONPATH=. where . means the current directory.  This allowed the PyImport_ImportModule("funcoes_python") to find the file funcoes_python in the current directory.  One other idea comes to my mind, when you invoke if (pFuncSoma && PyCallable_Check(pFuncSoma)) I think you should have an else to follow this and print an error message. This would confirm if the problem is with the resolution of the function.

I put the file path funcoes_python.py in PyImport and I also put an else to show the error, in addition I put setenv("PYTHONPATH", ".", 1) ; and still nothing. I'm trying with python 32 bits. With 64 bitz it presents several errors such as (.text+0x4e): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_Dealloc'. I still don't know why it isn't printing anything in ```./output` ``

Hey, after finishing cmd I was able to compile the code normally. I got the expected result. However, after finishing Visual Studio, I still can't do it.

@joe90_supermarionation Can you tell which python you are using whether it is 64 or 32 bit? and which compiler, is it Mingw 64 or 32?

I have 64bit python on Linux, with GCC compiler. I would avoid a 32bit build unless you specifically need it for some good reason.
